# Canvas: Double Buffering

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I like to create a little graphics lib with double buffering to avoid flickering.

So I create a double buffer strategy on a `Canvas`. I assume that I `strategy.getDrawGraphics()` returns the current back buffer (the buffer for drawing). Than I draw some stuff on the buffer. Now I assume that `strategy.show()` flips the back buffer with the front buffer, so that the back buffer get shown on screen. But I don't see a black rectangle when I run the following code:

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.setVisible(true);

final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
frame.add(canvas);

// Double Buffering
canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
final BufferStrategy strategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();

Graphics2D current = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
current.setColor(Color.BLACK);
current.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
strategy.show(); // flip back buffer with front buffer?
current.dispose();
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

Thread.sleep(1000);
frame.dispose();
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things...

1. You should avoid mixing heavy and light weight components (adding a `Canvas` to a `JFrame`)
2. You should avoid using `Thread.sleep`, long running loops or calling blocking methods (such as I/O) within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This could prevent you application from being painted (amongst other things).  Instead you should consider using something like a `javax.swing.Timer`, which will sleep in a background thread, but will be triggered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
3. Swing components are double buffered by default.

Take a look at...

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

For more details

Comment: Thank you. That is not realy the answer to my question but I follow your hints. I've replaced the `Canvas` by `JPanel`. Because I don't know on wich events the `paintComponent` is called, I'am using 2 `BufferedImages` and swapping all the times. This works fine without flickering. Also I put all the graphics methods of the engine, like `drawCircle` in `invokeAndWait` so I'am sure, that all changes on the `BufferedImage` and all calls to the `JPanel` are executed in UI Thread. This might be not very perfomant but it works great without flickering. Thats what I need :)